# QML QObject onDestroyed

Tags: qt, signals, qml, qtquick2, qobject

I can not connect to [`destroyed()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal emitted by [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html)-derived class. Is it a bug or has to be this way?

```
Connections {
    target: myobj 
    onDestroyed: {
        console.log("Deleting object " + myobj)
    }
}
```

> Main.qml:31:3: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDestroyed"

Comment: Try change onDestroyed to Component.onDestroyed

Comment: Component.onDestroyed will be called when Connections object will be destroyed. But I want to know when myobj will be destroyed

Comment: Shouldn't it be `onDestruction`?

Comment: No, QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDestruction"